# Extract a List of values for keys with the same prefix using @JsonPropperty

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

For this JSON:

```
{"key.a": "a", "key.b": "b"}
```

I want to load values "a" and "b" to List using @JsonProperty and Jackson. I tried:

```
@JsonProperty("key.*")
List<String> values;
```

But it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `JsonAnySetter` annotation, which will map any unknown *Json* property, on a setter method:

```java
private List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonAnySetter
public void setValues(String key, String value) {
  // You can perform a pattern validation on the key if wanted
  this.values.add(value);
}

public List<String> getValues() {
  return this.values;
}
```

An alternative solution would be to implement a custom `JsonSerializer` & `JsonDeSerializer` as well.